# I want to pass a selected choice from one text box to a second box

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

The first box autocompletes as the user types and selects one of the options. The value is coming from a database with 3 attributes: `id`, `name`, and `value`. I would like the `value` of the selected name from the first text box to automatically display in the second box. How do I carry the `value` of the `name` once the `name` is selected by the user?

index.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#auto').autocomplete(
        {
            source: "search.php?json",
            minLength: 3

        });
    });


</script>

 </head>

   <body>
    <p>Type the name of a band: <input type="text" id="auto" /></p>


   </body>
     </html>

       search php file 

             <?php
         $mysqli = taken off;
       $text = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['term']);

              $query = "SELECT name, salary FROM tag WHERE name LIKE '%$text%' ORDER BY     
                name ASC";
             $result = $mysqli->query($query);
            $json = '[';
               $first = true;
                 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                           {
                       if (!$first) { $json .=  ','; } else { $first = false; }
                   $json .= '{"value":"'.$row['name'].'"}';

                      }
                       $json .= ']';

                echo $json;

                     ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#auto').autocomplete(
        {
            source: "search.php?json",
            minLength: 3,
            close: function( event, ui ) { getSalary(document.getElementById('auto').value) },
            change: function( event, ui ) { getSalary(document.getElementById('auto').value) },
            select: function( event, ui ) { getSalary(document.getElementById('auto').value) }

        });
    });

    function getSalary(name_salary){
        $.post( "salary.php", { term: name_salary }, function(data) {                                           
                var test = JSON.parse(data);
                document.getElementById('autosalary').value = test.value;
                $( "#mincome" ).text(test.value); 

                     });    

        }       
     </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to append a trigger in the autocomplete, by doing something like this

```
$( '#auto' ).autocomplete({
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        var myValue = $(this).val();
        //Do what you want with your value
    }
});
```